# to_timestamp() function in spark is giving null values

Tags: datetime, pyspark, databricks, to-timestamp

So I read a csv file with schema:

```
mySchema = StructType([StructField("StartTime", StringType(), True),
                       StructField("EndTime", StringType(), True)])

data = spark.read.load('/mnt/Experiments/Bilal/myData.csv', format='csv', header='false', schema = mySchema)
data.show(truncate = False)
```

I get this:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|StartTime                  |EndTime                    |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|2018-12-24T03:03:31.8088926|2018-12-24T03:07:35.2802489|
|2018-12-24T03:13:25.7756662|2018-12-24T03:18:10.1018656|
|2018-12-24T03:23:32.9391784|2018-12-24T03:27:57.2195314|
|2018-12-24T03:33:31.0793551|2018-12-24T03:37:04.6395942|
|2018-12-24T03:43:54.1638926|2018-12-24T03:46:38.1188857|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Now when I convert these columns from stringtype to timestamptype using:

```
data = data.withColumn('StartTime', to_timestamp('StartTime', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
data = data.withColumn('EndTime', to_timestamp('EndTime', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
```

I get null values:

```
+---------+-------+
|StartTime|EndTime|
+---------+-------+
|null     |null   |
|null     |null   |
|null     |null   |
|null     |null   |
|null     |null   |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Please go through the above link and make necessary changes.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469438/pyspark-creating-timestamp-column)

Comment: @Prathik, Thanks for replying. I am already able to parse string to timestamp using to_timestamp(). But I want accuracy upto nano-seconds similar to string that I have shown.

Comment: There was a JIRA ticket for this issue. It states that the ticket is resolved, but, not sure why its still not working. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17914

Comment: @Gladiator, I really want timestamp column including milliseconds and nanoseconds part. Any clue or any idea?

Comment: what is your use case? I think, if you are just sorting, you can still have it as a string and it will work the same

Comment: @Gladiator Noop, not just sorting but bunch of other operations as well, like splitting two datetime ranges into 10 min intervals and day intervals. Calculating different values like duration and much more and for that accuracy upto nanoseconds is a must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve it by casting. Strangely It did not need format.
(Spark 2.4.0. Local mode on Windows 10)
The schema before casting.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- StartTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EndTime: string (nullable = true)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df2 = df.withColumn('StartTime', F.col('StartTime').cast("timestamp")) \
.withColumn('EndTime', F.col('EndTime').cast("timestamp"))
```

result

```
df2.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|StartTime                 |EndTime                   |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2018-12-24 03:03:31.808892|2018-12-24 03:07:35.280248|
|2018-12-24 03:13:25.775666|2018-12-24 03:18:10.101865|
|2018-12-24 03:23:32.939178|2018-12-24 03:27:57.219531|
|2018-12-24 03:33:31.079355|2018-12-24 03:37:04.639594|
|2018-12-24 03:43:54.163892|2018-12-24 03:46:38.118885|
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Check the schema

```
df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- StartTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- EndTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```